# Cannot parse the response of restTemplate.exchange

Tags: java, spring, http, resttemplate

I have the following code to submit a post http call:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set(TENANT_ID_HEADER, event.getTenantId());
HttpEntity<InputObj> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(inputObj, headers);
ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity,
                Object.class
            );
```

The call is successfully reaching the server and it returns a 200 success code

```
ResponseEntity.ok().body("Successfully handled the request");
```

I keep getting the following error after the call is done

> Exception while performing API call with message : Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'Successfully': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Successfully': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

I tried using RestTemplate with converters instead of the default one in `org.springframework.web.client`.
However, I still get the same error

Comment: which response are you expecting from this endpoint? Do you know what is response structure for this?

Comment: The body returned from the endpoint is posted above and that is the exact structure returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea would be to deserialize the response to `String` instead of `Object` as the response type.

Created a small demo.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("demo")
public class DemoController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> demo() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Successfully handled the request");
    }
}
```

Main logic with `RestTemplate`:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        var response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8081/demo",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                null,
                String.class
        );

        System.out.printf("Response Code: %s%n", response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.printf("Response Body: %s%n", response.getBody());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Response Code: 200 OK
Response Body: Successfully handled the request
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're returning response with Header "ContentType" application/json, which makes HttpMessageConverterExtractor pick a json HttpMessageConverter to read the response, and your response body is not valid json, hence the exception. You should change the response Header "ContentType" to "text/plain" instead. And consider using ResponseEntity to accept the response instead of Response for better readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

The response being returned from server side is not a JSON but just a string. You response content-type is json and the json converter is failing to parse a normal string as JSON and deserialise it into a POJO. Also if you expected text to be sent than convert the "produces" on server side to text/plain.

Comment: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].